# Session in master page asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, master-pages

I have master page containing **login** and **logout** button.

I want it visible and invisible when `session["Userid"]` is null.

How can I do that?

I know how to make visible and invisible

code is:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        //string s = Session["UserId"].ToString();
        if (Session["UserId"] != null)
        {
            divLogin.Visible = true;
            divLogout.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {

            divLogin.Visible = false;
            divLogout.Visible = true;
        }


    }
```

Please help.

Comment: how your current code is behaving?

Comment: check on jquery and then hide and show on behalf of this

Comment: you cannot mix and match client side with server side so using Jquery is incorrect. It seems the logic is inverted here. When session is null, it displays the logout div - it should be inverted

Comment: Quick question which no-one seems to have asked, is `Session["UserId"]` being set? Have you tried moving this out of the `OnInit` method and into the `Page_Load` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this with this code in HTML. Try,

```
<div id="divLogin" style="display: <%= Session["UserId"]!=null ? "none" : "block" %>">Your Login content</div>
<div id="divLogout" style="display: <%= Session["UserId"]==null ? "none" : "block" %>">Your Logout content</div>
```

Comment: Not working means what? You get the 'Logout content` or you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

You must set `runat="server"` for the div.

```
<div id="divLogin" runat="server"></div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
divLogin.visible=false;
```

Comment: <li runat="server" id="divLogin">
                                <a  href="SignIn.aspx">Login</a></li>

                                <li runat="server" id="divLogout">
                                <a  href="SignIn.aspx">Logout</a></li>
                                <li>

Comment: I did already! But not working.. i want somethin good in sessionn.. after sign in i am not getting session values.

Comment: `visible` should replace with `Visible`

Answer (score -1):

Use the logic in OnPreRender function as user login & logout always occurs after OnInit is called for the master page. So, during refresh you will get proper values but not the first time.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you can find the below information

> *Master pages behave like child controls on a page: the master page Init event occurs before the page Init and Load events, and the master page Load event occurs after the page Init and Load events.*

What I think is (most probably) you are setting the user's login information in the Login page's buttonClick event handler, which gets called after the OnInit of the master page. So when the master page's OnInit gets executed, Session already contains previous state (null during login and user information during logout)

Even if the login controls and login button are provided on the Master page, it is better to provide this logic in PreRender event.

---

*Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful.*

Comment: I would appreciate if the negative voter could please provide a reason. btw, I've extended my answer to include additional information